# Linking the layout of a sliderInput and a graph

Tags: shiny

I have a selectInput which is used to specify a sliderInput both in a sidebarPanel( or a fluidRow(column(4,). The sliderInput takes its min and max value from a dataset and is used to specify a graph. Since the data is not equally spaced it is possible to select an interval where no data is present. I would like a nice way to show where the data is located. Below I have made some sample code(without the needed graph) and attached a picture of what I want( or think I want. I am open for suggestions). I have tried fiddling around with a fluid row and renderPlot under the slider but I haven't managed to make them align. (such that the layout will still look nice when browser is rescaled). 
Preferably I would like the new graph to be ggplot2.

**Update**

Code have been updated with divibisans suggestion. I still have problems with proper alignment.

```
    library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
# data
df = data.frame("sub1" = c(1,10), "sub2" = c(5,90))
sub1_val = data.frame("x" = c(seq(1,4),seq(9,10)), "y" = rnorm(6))
sub2_val = data.frame("x" = c(seq(5,40),seq(85,90)), "y" = rnorm(42))
#
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(
        selectInput("sel",label = "Choose subject",
                    choices = names(df),
                    selected = "sub2")
        ,uiOutput("subjectUI")
      ),
      plotOutput("selPlot", width = "75%", height = "100px")
    ),
  mainPanel(
    h1("Let there be stuff"),
    plotOutput("plot")
  )
)
)
server <- function(input, output,session) {

  output$subjectUI <- renderUI({ 
       sliderInput("slide","This is a slide",
                         min = df[input$sel][1,],
                         max = df[input$sel][2,],
                         value = c(min,max),
                         width = "75%"
             )
    })
  output$selPlot <- renderPlot({
    switch(input$sel,
           "sub1" = if(!is.null(input$slide[2])){plotData = data.frame(xVar = seq(df[input$sel][1,],df[input$sel][2,]));plotData["yVar"] = 1*(plotData$xVar %in% sub1_val$x) },
           "sub2" = if(!is.null(input$slide[2])){plotData = data.frame(xVar = seq(df[input$sel][1,],df[input$sel][2,]));plotData["yVar"] = 1*(plotData$xVar %in% sub2_val$x) })
    if(!is.null(input$slide[2])){
      ggplot(data = plotData, aes(x = xVar, y = yVar)) +
        geom_point() + geom_line() +
        geom_vline(xintercept = input$slide[1]) +
        geom_vline(xintercept = input$slide[2]) +
        labs(x = "", y="")  +
        scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) + 
        theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
              axis.text.y = element_blank(),
              axis.ticks.y = element_blank())
    }
    })
  #
  output$plot <- renderPlot(
    switch(input$sel,
           "sub1" = if(!is.null(input$slide[2])){vec = sub1_val$x>= input$slide[1] & sub1_val$x <= input$slide[2];plot(sub1_val$x[vec],sub1_val$y[vec],type ="b")},
           "sub2" = if(!is.null(input$slide[1])){vec = sub2_val$x>= input$slide[1] & sub2_val$x <= input$slide[2];plot(sub2_val$x[vec],sub2_val$y[vec],type ="b")}
           )
  )
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[How I imagine a solution could look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXO9x.png)

[My second attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IzPf.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would render a second plot with all the data and then have `input$slide[1]` and `input$slide[2]` change the position of two vertical lines that mark the selected area. I wrote it in ggplot since I don't really understand how you generated your plot, but presumably it would be simple enough to draw a vertical line on a plot using that system. Something like this:

```
output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = DATA, aes(x = XVAR, y = YVAR)) +
        geom_point() + geom_line() +
        geom_vline(xintercept = input$slide[1]) +
        geom_vline(xintercept = input$slide[2])
})
```

Comment: I tried implementing your suggestion but the problem is that the plot is not tied to the slide so when you change the browser window they do not seem to change exactly the same way. Furthermore, even when I strip the plot of all its legends the left side of the plot does not align with the slider.

Comment: Are you talking about the alignment and positioning of elements on the page? That's actually pretty with shiny, since each shiny tag usually generates several HTML tags with their own CSS. For this problem, you could try specifying an absolute width for both elements and play with it until they line up the way you want to. Unfortunately, getting them to line up just right is going to require some messing around with CSS.

Comment: Yes the alignment is the problem. Since my CSS skills are somewhat limited I had hoped for a mint shiny solution. If you have any CSS suggestions feel free to share.